# ajax is not getting post id by click on a fref in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am working with laravel. I want to save a post as accepted on click using ajax.
I am sending post using a href tag. 
I don't want to use form for this. 
here how I am sending post id to ajax

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="acceptProject({{$project->id}})" class="btn-accept">Accept</a>
```

Here is my js function

```
function acceptProject($id) {
  var projectId;
  $.ajax({
    alert(projectId);
  });
}
```

but it is showing unexpected token in the console. This is very first week that I am writing ajax code so any mistake please consider.